# MySQL Left Outer Join with Count from joined table, Show all records

Tags: mysql, count, left-join

i am trying to create a query where there is a count of related records from another table. I'd like the "parent" records whether there are related records (a count) or not.

```
SELECT r.region_name, r.region_id, r.abbreviation, r.map_order,
    (IFNULL( COUNT( p.property_id ) , 0 )) AS propertyCount
FROM  `rmp_region` r
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `rmp_property` p 
    ON p.path LIKE CONCAT(  '%/', r.region_id,  '/%' ) 
WHERE p.active =1
AND r.parent_region_id =1
GROUP BY r.region_name, r.region_id, r.abbreviation, r.map_order
ORDER BY r.map_order ASC
```

I've tried different variations of this.. but i cannot get the parent records to display if the count is zero/no related records.

thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move "p.active = 1" from the WHERE clause into the OUTER JOIN criteria.

Here's your example with the change:

```
SELECT r.region_name, r.region_id, r.abbreviation, r.map_order,
    (IFNULL( COUNT( p.property_id ) , 0 )) AS propertyCount
FROM  `rmp_region` r
LEFT OUTER JOIN  `rmp_property` p 
    ON p.path LIKE CONCAT(  '%/', r.region_id,  '/%' ) and p.active =1
WHERE r.parent_region_id =1
GROUP BY r.region_name, r.region_id, r.abbreviation, r.map_order
ORDER BY r.map_order ASC
```

Comment: any ideas on optimizing this? I'm a mysql newbie.. i've added indexes to the path column.. but didn't seem to do much. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You asked about optimizing it, hoping that a index on the "path" column might help.  Unfortunately you are searching for a value of path that matches `LIKE CONCAT(  '%/', r.region_id,  '/%' )`, and no index in the world is smart enough to work with that.